# jinja2 basename or dirname from builtin filters?

Tags: python-2.7, jinja2

Is there any way of doing a `basename` or `dirname` in jinja2 using only builtin filters? E.g. something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import jinja2

mybin = '/my/favorite/full/path/foo'
t = jinja2.Template("my binary is {{ mybin }}")
print t.render()
t = jinja2.Template("my basename is {{ mybin|basename() }}")
print t.render()
t = jinja2.Template("my dirname is {{ mybin|dirname() }}")
print t.render()

1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If you found this question & are **using Ansible**, then these filters [do exist in Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-file-names-and-path-names).

To get the last name of a file path, like ‘foo.txt’ out of ‘/etc/asdf/foo.txt’:

```
{{ path | basename }}
```

To get the directory from a path:

```
{{ path | dirname }}
```

**Without Ansible**, it's easy to add custom filters to Jinja2:

```
def basename(path):
    return os.path.basename(path)

def dirname(path):
    return os.path.dirname(path)
```

You register these in the template environment by updating the filters dictionary in the environment, prior to rendering the template:

```
environment.filters['basename'] = basename
environment.filters['dirname']  = dirname
```

Comment: saltstack now has `{{ salt['file.dirname'](path) }}` https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.file.html#salt.modules.file.dirname)

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple, if you think about it, it's just tokenization using `/`, so for `basename` you split your string by slashes into a list, then get the last element from that list:

```
{{ mybin.split('/') | last }}
```

---

`dirname` is a bit more tricky:

```
{{ mybin.split('/')[:-1] | join('/') }}
```

Again, you explode the string by slashes, then take that list from the first item (`:`) until the penultimate item (`-1`), then join them back together.

---

Easy as pie, right? Jinja2 often drives me crazy, but at the same time it's an incredibly powerful and often really efficient language :)

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be a built in filter to get the physical base path.

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters

Here's how you could pass the current physical path.

```
import os


tmpl = env.get_template('index.html')
return tmpl.render(folder=os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Hope this helps!